# Nuget package with native libraries for sdk and non-sdk project types and with supporting multitargetting (net452, netstandard20, netstandard21)

Tags: xamarin, nuget, packaging, csproj, multitargeting

I have a NuGet package that supports 3 different `TF`s and should be available for consumers(apps) in `Non-sdk` (old `csproj` format) and `Sdk` (a new one) `csproj` files. My nugget also contains `native` libraries for Windows, Linux, and mac os.

The only problem I have is related to the processing of native libraries.
I configure it in this way (also there are similar steps that cover non-windows `OS`s):

```
<!--IsWindows is defined in the first steps-->

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(IsWindows)' == 'true' ">
  <Content Include="$(MyLibrariesPathInTheSolution)/nativeWindowsLibrary.dll">
    <Pack>true</Pack>
    <PackagePath>runtimes/win/native</PackagePath>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(IsWindows)' == 'true' ">
  <Content Include="$(MyLibrariesPathInTheSolution)/nativeWindowsLibrary.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <Link>nativeWindowsLibrary.dll</Link>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

the above configuration works well for `sdk` projects but doesn't cover `non-sdk`s. So, I added one more step into the main `csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(IsWindows)' == 'true' ">
  <Content Include="MyApp.targets">
    <Pack>true</Pack>
    <PackagePath>build</PackagePath>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

where MyApp.targets looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--IsWindows is also defined here, skipped this definition just to reduce the number of lines-->

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(IsWindows)' == 'true' ">
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../runtimes/win/native/nativeWindowsLibrary.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>nativeWindowsLibrary.dll</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

the above fixes the consumer's issue related to `non-sdk` projects, but triggers a problem if a consumer uses `xamarin` + `mac OS` because this platform tries to process `nativeWindowsLibrary.dll` (`MacOS-built` library is processed also but it's expected unlike `Windows-built`) during building even though there is the condition on `OS = Windows` (which is `false` for this case).

So, my main question is there any guide (example) about how to create a NuGet package for the above case where we need to support:

- non-sdk and SDK csproj files
- different target frameworks
- platform related libraries (which are placed in `runtimes`)

also, are there any suggestions about the provided configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug in xamarin https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10337 related to the mono msbuild issue
https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/15569